# Moderator declines flag for a duplicate answer, explaining that the duplicate answer arguably adds more value

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, duplicate-answers

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334636/javascript-yes-no-alert/33469030#33469030) has two near-identical answers.

I flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334636/javascript-yes-no-alert/33469030#33469030) (note: answer was removed in the meantime, so link doesn't work anymore):

> ```
> var answer = confirm("Save data?")
>
> if (answer){
>        //some code if yes
> }
> else{
>        //other code if no
> }
> ```

---

as a duplicate (copy) of this (older, lots of up-votes) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9334679/2275490):

> ```
> var answer = confirm("Save data?")
> if (answer){
>        //some code
> }
> else{
>         //some code
> }
> ```
>
> Use confirm instead of alert. This is the easiest way to achieve that
>   functionality.

---

explaining the flag with:

> this answer is a copy of second highly voted answer by Chuck Norris
>   [stackoverflow.com/a/9334679/2275490](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9334679/2275490), the only thing he changed was
>   adding "if yes" and "if no" at the commented code

Well, the flag was declined by a moderator for this reason:

> its fairly boilerplate code, and arguably the "if yes", and "if no"
>   add some more detail to the answer

My question is: Was this a mistake by the moderator? If not, what is the threshold to qualify an answer as a duplicate (copy)?

Comment: if moderators statement: 'arguably the "if yes", and "if no" add some more detail to the answer' is true, my flag should not have been declined, right?

Comment: That answer is way at the bottom, certainly plausible that the answerer simply didn't see it. He/she also has no other answers, so it's hard to judge whether or not this user did this with malicious intent.

Comment: @KevinB that's why I added the corresponding links and explained when flagging

Comment: No, you missed my point. I'm sure the moderator was aware, but maybe the answerer wasn't. This is such a simple question that it's not difficult to imagine two people giving such similar answers. in this case there are actually 6 answers that use this technique (several of them deleted)

Comment: yes I see, anyway back to my question what makes an answer a duplicate?

Comment: well... there's nothing wrong with  "duplicate" answer (other than it not adding value), the problem arises when it is plagiarized. you can't prove it was plagiarized in this case, and there's no history with this user to base a decision on either.

Comment: to be fair though... one of the deleted ones were deleted for the same reason, presumably from a flag like yours.

Comment: @KevinB so we want to encourage to copy-paste an accepted answer or a highly up-voted answer, change a little bit in the comment and post it as a new answer?

Comment: @KevinB I've flagged duplicated content that adds nothing new, and have got it deleted.

Comment: @Braiam: the moderator writes: "its fairly boilerplate code, and arguably the "if yes", and "if no" add some more detail to the answer" and then declines the flag? that was a mistake !

Comment: I'm not seeing how that answer adds anything new to the preexisting one. In fact the older at least have a note why confirm is better than just alert.

Comment: @Braiam exactly that is the reason why I flagged it. The moderator who declined the flag saw it as well, but instead of getting rid of the dupe answer they declined my flag...

Comment: the dupe answer has been deleted, but my flag maintains declined. I can live with that :)

Comment: FYI: Mods are people too, they can also make mistakes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I declined your flag. At the time, I did it intentionally, because I thought the "duplicate" added *something* (admittedly negligible) to the question.

In retrospect, it might have been *soooooo* negligible, I should have just deleted it. Or at least marked your flag as helpful.

Comment: you are welcome to reverse the flag. And thanks for answering.

Comment: @Vickel: moderators cannot reverse flag decisions.

Comment: as I wrote in the question comment, no big deal, I can live with it :)

Comment: If the comments made the control flow clearer, they should have been improved in the original answer. This is the kind of trivial added value that should be achieved through edits, not duplication of the entire answer. Unfortunately, some people are wedded to a foolish notion that code is somehow sacred and therefore off-limits to editors.

Comment: i don't think you did anything wrong in declining the flag, because its programming and some things are meant to be written in specific format and if someone posts it before that does not means anyone else should not post answer. @CodyGray `some people are wedded to a foolish notion that code is somehow sacred and therefore off-limits to editors` it must be a programming quote.  Just my thoughts no offence