# My answer was duplicated a minute after mine was posted. Was my downvote reasonable?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, downvotes, duplicate-answers

I recently answered this post: [Error on findViewById - Subsampling Scale Image View - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754081/error-on-findviewbyid-subsampling-scale-image-view-android/39754114?noredirect=1#comment66804431_39754114)

and a minute later it got another answer which was the same as mine but actually less useful as mine explained the answer and simply provided the code.

I downvoted his answer and flagged it. Were my actions right? Should I have just flagged him or not flagged him at all, or simply downvoted him without flagging? I kind of blew off steam since I was **very pissed off** after he downvoted me as a reaction to my downvote. I understand that was wrong; but I'm not sure if I was wrong (*not saying he wasn't wrong in downvoting my answer*) in flagging him and down-voting him.

Comment: Nope. If you can answer it in 2 minutes, it's certainly plausible that someone else could come to the same conclusion in two minutes. Since this isn't a case of plagiarism, there's nothing that needs to be done here.

Comment: There's generally nothing wrong with a question having two answers stating mostly the same thing, and "I was here first' is not really a good reason to downvote other answers.

Comment: @Servy as I said, I just blew off steam. I will remove them

Comment: @animuson I had another reason to downvote; just giving the code is way too localized. My answer is clearly much more useful

Comment: @AbAppletic _"after he downvoted me as a reaction to my downvote"_ How do you actually know?

Comment: but... giving the code could be seen as more useful than just describing the problem/solution with words...

Comment: @KevinB well then, guess what? I did both. Obviously better than just throwing up the code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ nothing could be more obvious; he asked me why I downvoted and I got downvoted. The views on the post at that time can prove it.

Comment: @AbAppletic You're wrong. It could well be coincidence. Even it the other OP drops -1 rep at the same time. Give a certain proof for your assumption.

Comment: @animuson and to add more, check this post out: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318480/moderator-declines-flag-for-a-duplicate-answer-explaining-that-the-duplicate-an?rq=1 . Clearly, flags for duplicate answers should be deleted and will be rejected if it adds more value. My answer clearly has more value.

Comment: Being picky but there is only a 21 second difference in post time so they should really be considered to be posted at the same time.

Comment: @JoeW that's not really my point. My answer clearly has more value.

Comment: @AbAppletic Then you'll get the upvotes and/or acceptance.

Comment: @AbAppletic That answer doesn't support your point. In that case, a near-duplicate (by duplicate I mean almost no difference whatsoever) was posted *several years* later. We do **not** just delete answers because they are similar to each other.

Comment: @animuson what I mean is my answer **does have more value**.  And the fact that an answer which: 1- was posted after my post 2- is less valuable than mine gets more upvotes is just absurd and unfair; and you should definitely take it into attention, just as you take every single detail into attention on this site. You take your steps so high to commit "fair play" on this site yet you take no attention to cases like this. Absurd. You're so strict on your rules yet you lack logic. You care so much about quality of answers yet you lack fairness. What a terrible system.

Comment: If your answer has more value then it will be upvoted above the other answer. That's how the system works. We don't need to bother other people to delete "less valuable" answers on the site. That's a waste of time. So long as it provides an answer, there's nothing wrong with it being there.

Comment: People will vote on questions based on meta posts like this even if they shouldn't be. All your complaints in this are not helping you at all.

Comment: @animuson the same way you can delete duplicate questions, you can delete duplicate answers. That's not a waste of time, is it?

Comment: Duplicate questions get closed not deleted in most cases.

Comment: We don't delete duplicate questions, though. We encourage users to keep them around so that users who search for a problem in a different way can find their way to that other question easily. In fact, questions closed as duplicates are explicitly ignored in many of the automated deletion scripts.

Comment: @AbAppletic Answering questions that should be closed as a typo is problematic as it stops the system from auto deleting it.

Answer (score 9):

So the first question to consider is whether plagiarism is happening.  If you have reasonable suspicion that another user is plagiarizing your answer by actually taking your content and using it inappropriately in their own answer, then that is very bad, and you should be flagging for moderator attention.  Having said that, this case seems very clearly not plagiarism.  The answer contains no original content from your answer, so clearly that's not relevant in this case.

Next, you bring up the issue of similar answers to the question being posted as an issue.  The typical convention in this regard is to ignore cases where the answers were posted at close to the same time, to the point where it's reasonable that both started writing the answer without seeing the other.  What you'll often find being discouraged is providing answers that add no additional value over other answers that had been posted days, or even *years* earlier.  Of course, these are just common conventions, and by no means rules, so as a consequence you shouldn't be flagging posts because you think that other answers already conveyed that information, but many users do choose to downvote such answers as a result of feeling that they aren't useful.

You also mention that you think the answer is inferior (while also saying that it was the same, which is a contradiction).  If you feel that an answer is not useful as a result of not being sufficiently clear, then by all means, reflect this in your vote.  Votes are there to indicate whether or not a post is *useful*, not just whether it is technically correct.  A correct answer that is confusing, or fails to properly convey the important information to readers is not a useful answer, and we *want* votes to reflect that.  This of course has no bearing on when a post was posted.  An unclear answer posted first is no different than an unclear answer posted after another answer.